# Get next of given DateTime and skip if day is not the same

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

I want to get next month's date and time from the given date and time. Here is what i have now:

```
$dt = new DateTime('2019-01-31');

for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $dt->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
    $final = $dt->format('Y-m-d');
    echo $final."\n";
}

// Output:
// 2019-03-03
// 2019-04-03
// 2019-05-03
// 2019-06-03
// 2019-07-03
```

The problem is, it changes the day from "31" to "02" because in February, there is no day 31. So in the months that don't have for example 30, or 31, I want to skip those months but keep the days the same.

So here should be the **expected** output:

```
// 2019-03-31
// 2019-05-31
// 2019-07-31
// 2019-08-31
// 2019-10-31
```

How can I do that?

Comment: A really well formed and formatted SO question getting immediately to the point and showing the own approach, output and expected result. I wish all contibutors would do it like that. +1

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone Haha thanks! I kinda realized it after I had posted the question :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of reliably doing this is to keep adding more months to the start date, rather than continually adding one month. Then you can compare the day of the new date with that of the start date, and if they are the same, echo the result:

```
$dt = new DateTime('2019-01-31');
$day = $dt->format('d');
for ($i=1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $next = clone $dt;
    $next->add(new DateInterval("P{$i}M"));
    if ($next->format('d') != $day) continue;
    echo $next->format('Y-m-d') ."\n";
}
```

Output:

```
2019-03-31
2019-05-31 
2019-07-31 
2019-08-31 
2019-10-31
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/oR5A3)

**Update**

If you want to output 10 months from the start (that meet the day condition), you can use this code, which counts the number of outputs:

```
$dt = new DateTime('2019-01-31');
$day = $dt->format('d');
$months = 0;
for ($i=1; $months < 10; $i++) {
    $next = clone $dt;
    $next->add(new DateInterval("P{$i}M"));
    if ($next->format('d') != $day) continue;
    echo $next->format('Y-m-d') ."\n";
    $months++;
}
```

Output:

```
2019-03-31 
2019-05-31 
2019-07-31 
2019-08-31 
2019-10-31 
2019-12-31
2020-01-31 
2020-03-31
2020-05-31 
2020-07-31
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/imvZ8)

Answer (score 3):

It's a little tricky because your `DateTime()` object keeps changing. But basically you need to:

1. keep track of the day of the month
2. modify the date so it goes to the first of the month so you don't skip any months
3. add a month
4. check the length of the month and skip it if it is too short
5. format your date putting back the correct day.

.

```
<?php
$dt = new DateTime('2019-01-31');
$day = $dt->format('d');
for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $dt->modify('first day of this month')->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
    if ($dt->format('t') < $day) {
        continue;
    }
    $final = $dt->format('Y-m-' . $day);
    echo $final."\n";
}
```

Output

```
2019-03-31
2019-05-31
2019-07-31
2019-08-31
2019-10-31
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/evnLo)

Here's an example showing 10 results. There's a lot of ways to do this through loops. I chose a do/while loop since I think they don't get used enough. :)

```
<?php

$dt = new DateTime('2019-01-31');
$day = $dt->format('d');
$i = 0;
do {
    $dt->modify('first day of this month')->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
    if ($dt->format('t') < $day) {
        continue;
    }
    $final = $dt->format('Y-m-' . $day);
    echo $final."\n";
    $i++;
} while ($i < 10);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/SLOgi)

Comment: How can I not upvote your answer when they're so similar? :-)

Comment: @Nick Both +1 for the probably shortest form in PHP. However, even more important the relatively new OP should be upvoted for clearly getting to the point, showing his own approach, the output and the expected result as well.

Comment: Great answer guys! But how can it go back to January once it reaches the end of the year? Since the for loop `i = 10`, it should show 10 results.

Comment: I updated my answer to show 10 results. Both answer work equally well and are just a matter of preference. Hopefully they help demonstrate how you can do things more than one way in PHP.

Comment: Yes thank you so much! I accepted Nick's answer since it was pretty much where I was going with but +1 for such a unique approach!